# WPF Background Pattern

Tags: c#, wpf, drawingbrush

I'm searching for the best method to make `pattern` for `background` of `canvas`. I want to show user canvas with drawed lines, which will show borders for different size of document, e.g. Paper A4.
I'v made it by using `DrawingBrush` in XAML. Here is my code:

```
<DrawingBrush x:Key="BackgroundPattern" ViewportUnits="Absolute" Stretch="None" TileMode="Tile">
        <DrawingBrush.Viewport>
            <Rect X="0" Y="0" Width="1089" Height="1842"/>
        </DrawingBrush.Viewport>
        <DrawingBrush.Drawing>
            <DrawingGroup>
                <GeometryDrawing Brush="Blue">
                    <GeometryDrawing.Geometry>
                        <GeometryGroup>
                            <RectangleGeometry>
                                <RectangleGeometry.Rect>
                                    <Rect X="0" Y="0" Width="1089" Height="1842"/>
                                </RectangleGeometry.Rect>
                            </RectangleGeometry>
                        </GeometryGroup>
                    </GeometryDrawing.Geometry>
                </GeometryDrawing>
                <GeometryDrawing Brush="#FFB9B9B9">
                    <GeometryDrawing.Geometry>
                        <GeometryGroup>
                            <RectangleGeometry>
                                <RectangleGeometry.Rect>
                                    <Rect X="1" Y="1" Width="1088" Height="1841"/>
                                </RectangleGeometry.Rect>
                            </RectangleGeometry>
                        </GeometryGroup>
                    </GeometryDrawing.Geometry>
                </GeometryDrawing>
            </DrawingGroup>
        </DrawingBrush.Drawing>
    </DrawingBrush>
```

I'm using this brush in `tile` mode, there is effect:
[image]

I'm afraid of the size of my elements - `Viewport` size is 1089x1842. Is there any other way to make these?

Answer (score 2):

Although the size of a WPF Drawing shouldn't matter (because it is not a bitmap), you could probably simplify it like this:

```
<DrawingBrush x:Key="BackgroundPattern" ViewportUnits="Absolute" Viewport="0,0,1089,1842"
    AlignmentX="Left" AlignmentY="Top" Stretch="None" TileMode="Tile">
    <DrawingBrush.Drawing>
        <GeometryDrawing Brush="#FFB9B9B9">
            <GeometryDrawing.Pen>
                <Pen Thickness="1" Brush="Blue"/>
            </GeometryDrawing.Pen>
            <GeometryDrawing.Geometry>
                <RectangleGeometry Rect="0,0,1089,1842"/>
            </GeometryDrawing.Geometry>
        </GeometryDrawing>
    </DrawingBrush.Drawing>
</DrawingBrush>
```

Comment: So it is better to use WPF Drawing than put and repeat bitmap?

Comment: Sure, but your approach was already a drawing. I was just referring to your "I'm afraid of the size of my elements".